# How to make a polynomial approximation in Scilab?

Tags: polynomial-math, scilab, approximation

I've a set of measures, which I want to approximate. I know I can do that with a 4th degree polynomial, but I don't know how to find it's five coefficients using Scilab.

For now, I must use the user-friendly functions of Open office calc... So, to keep using only Scilab, I'd like to know if a built-in function exists, or if we can use a simple script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no built-in `polyfit` function like in Matlab, but you can make your own:

```
function cf = polyfit(x,y,n)
A = ones(length(x),n+1)
for i=1:n
    A(:,i+1) = x(:).^i
end
cf = lsq(A,y(:))
endfunction
```

This function accepts two vectors of equal size (they can be either row or column vectors; colon operator makes sure they are column-oriented in the computation) and the degree of polynomial.

It returns the column of coefficients, ordered from 0th to the nth degree.

The computational method is straightforward: set up the (generally, overdetermined) linear system that requires the polynomial to pass through every point. Then solve it in the sense of least squares with `lsq` (in practice, it seems that `cf = A\y(:)` performs identically, although the algorithm is a bit different there).

Example of usage:

```
x = [-3 -1 0 1 3 5 7]
y = [50 74 62 40 19 35 52]
cf = polyfit(x,y,4)

t = linspace(min(x),max(x))'   // now use these coefficients to plot the polynomial
A = ones(length(t),n+1)
for i=1:n
    A(:,i+1) = t.^i
end
plot(x,y,'r*')
plot(t,A*cf)
```

Output:

[image: polynomial fit]

Answer (score 4):

The Atom's toolbox "stixbox" has Matlab-compatible "polyfit" and "polyval" functions included.

```
// Scilab 6.x.x need:
atomsInstall(["stixbox";"makematrix";"distfun";"helptbx";linalg"]) // install toolboxes

// POLYNOMINAL CURVE_FITTING
// Need toolboxes above

x = [-3 -1 0 1 3 5 7];
y = [50 74 62 40 19 35 52];
plot(x,y,".");           // plot sample points only

pcoeff = polyfit(x,y,4); // calculate polynominal coefficients (4th-degree)
xp = linspace(-3,7,100); // generate a little more x-values for a smoother curve fitting
yp = polyval(pcoeff,xp); // calculate the y-values for the curve fitting
plot(xp, yp,"k");        // plot the curve fitting in black
```

[image]